# PrimeNG DataTable: change class/style of a cell

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

How can I add a class to **a cell** depending on field value?

```
<p-dataTable [value]="invoices" tableStyleClass="table-invoices">
    <p-column field="status" header="Status" styleClass="mini status">
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-col let-inv="rowData">
            {{inv.status}}
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I know how to add class to all cells in a column, but I need to give a class to cells (`<td>`) individually, depending on the value stored in `status`, so some cells in a column will have the class and some others in the same column won't.

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/NqwSn5zWZ9mIuVNcbLBi/)

**Edited**: I know how to give a class to a HTML element inside the `<td>`, but I want to know if it's possible to give a class to the `<td>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can style a template:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="invoices" tableStyleClass="table-invoices">
    <p-column field="status" header="Status" styleClass="mini {{rowData}}" >
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-col let-inv="rowData">
            <div [class.decorated]="inv.status == 1">{{inv.status}}</div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

[plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/qzpt5E8I9WvfuWKdJk9r/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to style the cell, not an html element inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In order to style the whole cell you will have to find the TD element that hosts your ng-template.  To do this, I implemented a directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[cellFormatting]'
})
export class CellFormattingDirective {
    @Input() cellFormatting: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let target = this.el.nativeElement;
        let td = target.closest('td');
        if (td) {
            //apply some conditions here using data.cellFormatting
            td.style.backgroundColor = 'darkorange';
            td.style.color = 'white';
        }
    }
}
```

The I used it in the markup as :

```
<ng-template let-col let-data="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <div [id]="col.field" class="cell-content" [cellFormatting]="data">
        <div [innerHTML]="data[col.field]" class="center-parent-screen"></div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Once you have a reference to the TD element, you can apply any CSS transformations you want.

This approach does not feel like the "Angular" way, but currently, this is the only way I managed to accomplish this.